# ready method not getting called in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have the following code in my html page to create Menu. When the user clicks on the Menu, 
it shows three links for three pages.

```
var menu = [{
    title: "Home",
    url: "simple-page-a.html"
}, {
    title: "My Disputes",
    url: "simple-page-b.html"
}, {
    title: "Search Disputes",
    url: "simple-page-c.html"
}];


// For this "simple demo" we can change event to "pageinit", but for the more advanced features, it has to be bound to "pageshow"
$(document).on("pageshow", function (event) {
    var items = '', // menu items list
        ul = $(".mainMenu:empty"); // get "every" mainMenu that has not yet been processed
    for (var i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
        items += '<li><a href="' + menu[i].url + '">' + menu[i].title + '</a></li>';
    }
    ul.append(home);
    ul.listview('refresh'); // use cache, as ".mainMenu:empty" will no longer work (append called!)
});
```

In the simple-page-b.html page , i have the below code

```
<script> 
   $(document).ready(function() {
     methodA(); 
   });
</script>
```

When i navigate to simple-page-b.html from the menu, ready method is not getting called ,

even i tried with `onload()`, still not working. But if i refresh the simple-page-b.html page, ready gets called.

How do i make this `function(ready)` called when i navigate by menu as shown above.

Comment: Can someone pleas answer my question ?

Comment: which jQM version are you using?

Comment: Hello Omar, 

Thanks for your response. This is what I have in the header section

<head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>index</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
      <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
      <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>

This is worklight. Not sure which version its using. 
     </head>